# Running Ionic 2 app on Windows Phone 10

Tags: ionic2, uwp, windows-phone, windows-10-universal, ionic3

I developed a Ionic 2 app and I can't find a way to run it on Windows Phone 10 device that is connected to my PC. How can I make it run?

Thanks

Comment: What error did you get? What IDE did you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried with [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/platform-setup/windows-setup.html):

> To build apps for Windows Universal, download and install Visual
>   Studio 2015 Community Edition. During the installation, Select “Tools
>   for Cross Platform Development” as well as the SDK for Windows
>   Universal Apps.
>
> With everything installed, you’ll be able to add a windows platform
>   from the command line with this command:

```
ionic platform add windows
```

> By default the build command produces two packages: Windows 8.1 and
>   Windows Phone 8.1, which Ionic does not support. To upgrade Windows
>   package to version 10 the following configuration setting must be
>   added to configuration file (config.xml).

```
<preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```